# "The underlying provider failed on Open" while reaching sql azure db with a WCF dataservice inside a webrole

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, azure-sql-database

"The underlying provider failed on Open" while reaching sql azure db with a WCF dataservice inside a webrole in the development Fabric.

Opened VS 2010 in admin mode.

Created a new windows azure project.

Added a webrole.

Added a ADO.NET entity data model to a database in SQL azure.This established the connection properly, read all the tables and generated the model. Used the standard sql authentication while connecting to the Azure database.

Added a WCF data service project.

When I **F5** the solution. the service definition opens up correctly showing the tables that are existing in the model.
but when I add a table name to the URL (which is when the actual connection to the database is made) the above error comes up in a HTTP 500 response.

**NOTE:** I am able to connect to the SQL Azure database from SSMS .

Able to connect to it while generating the entity  data model.

When I host the solution in Windows Azure web role everything works fine.

But it does not work when I try to do it in the Development emulator of VS2010.
Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I have no idea why this is happening.
HAving in mind it works in Azure Web Role (are you deploying to real azure account?) and from your SSMS, I assume you have either disabled the SQL Azure Firewall, or open it for access from Windows Azure Servives and your public IP Address.
The only question remaining is to double check the Connection string. When you hit F5 can you break at the error and see the actual connection string which is being used locally? That might give you a hing why you are failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting from your local dev box to SQL Azure you will need to add a firewall rule in the portal for everything to work properly. Check and make sure you have enabled a firewall rule in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds uncannily like the one I've just been experiencing. I found that the advice on the following thread helped me: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/ca5887aa-7720-41bb-af8a-1633347be1c5

The cure, in my case at least, was to comment out the "sites" section of the ServiceDefinition config file. HTH